# WPS office take the html opened file from chrome when pressing a link

Tags: android, google-chrome

I am saving the offline docs of android development in my SD and I am opening them with chrome and when I press any link it takes me to WPS office even do not asking I tried clear defaults but nothing changed

Answer (score 1):

I have the same question, just add this function in your code:

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
  @Override
  public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
    if(url!=""){
      view.loadUrl(url);   
      System.out.println("url:"+url);
    }
    return true;
  }
});
```

Comment: thank you for the answer, but it is not in coding my app, it is in my mobile just using WPS office and Chrome normally